# Detect a specific shape using OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, pattern-matching, shapes, matching

I'm still a beginner in OpenCV.

Currently, I'm trying to detect a specific shape as in the image in the link below using OpenCV.

[image]

I've read many blogs and articles about detecting shapes using OpenCV but I've not found anything related to what I'm working on.

Also, I can't use methods like  cvHistogram, because I don't want to find matches in two almost identical pictures, but instead, I want to detect a specific shape, and not some geometric shapes like rectangles, circles, etc.

Do you know a way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question can use a little refinement: what is the shape you are looking for? what are the methods you tried and did not work for you? why are you not satisfied with other methods you saw in blogs etc?

Comment: If only things were that easy... all you would need to do in this case is detect whether a curve is open or closed. In the binary case this is trivial to do when it doesn't intersect with other lines. But I believe your example doesn't represent your actual problem. Would you care to post a real example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say how to detect this shape. You should specify some criterions about shape that you want to detect. For example in your case:

1. should this always be inside another contour?
2. should it has that big black blob?

And so on.

And after this it will be easier to find good detection algorithm.

By the way reading these docs will be useful:

1. [Finding contours in your image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)
2. [Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html)